# how to find a folder using applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get applescript to find a folder and then eventually open every item in it using Preview.  I can get preview to open a folder but it's opening the wrong folder. This is what I have so far:

```
    set dFolder to "/Users/bobsmith/Desktop/screencapture"
    tell application "Preview"
open every item of dFolder
end tell
```

I should think I should at least be able to see the contents of the folder in the debugger but I do not.

```
tell application "Finder"
set dFolder to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/bobsmith/Desktop/screencapture" as alias list
```

end tell

Answer (score 2):

I combined your two scripts and it worked for me... (I suspect Preview didn't like getting passed a string, which your first line was doing???)

```
set myFiles to missing value
tell application "Finder"
    set myFiles to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/bobsmith/Desktop/screencapture" as alias list
end tell

tell application "Preview"
    open every item of myFiles
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is **omit `every item of`**:

```applescript
set dFolder to "/Users/bobsmith/Desktop/screencapture"
tell application "Preview"
  activate
  open dFolder
end tell
```

Note: The `activate` is needed for *robustness*: inexplicably, as of macOS 10.12.4, if `Preview` isn't already running, the command is quiet no-op.

Or, in a **generalized and streamlined** reformulation:

```applescript
tell application "Preview"
  activate
  open POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "screencapture"
end tell
```

Note that this will:

- open files in the target folder *recursively*; i.e., not just in the target folder itself, but in its entire folder *subtree*.
- open all files (typically) in a *single* document window.

Explanation:

- `path to desktop` evaluates to a filesystem `alias` representing the current user's desktop.
- `POSIX path of` converts that `alias` to a POSIX-style path, including a trailing `/`; e.g.: `/Users/bobsmith/Desktop/`
- String-appending `screencapture` with `&` therefore yields something like `/Users/bobsmith/Desktop/screencapture`
- `Preview` apparently understands POSIX folder paths (verified on macOS 10.12), and implicitly opens all files located in the specified folder and its subtree.

---

One drawback to using a POSIX path *string* directly is that Preview quietly *ignores* a nonexistent path.
If you want to **verify beforehand that the target folder exists**:

```applescript
# This statement will fail, if the resulting path doesn't exist.
set fldr to alias (POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "screencapture" as POSIX file)

tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open fldr
end tell
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

Since `dfolder` is defined as a *string*, `every item` enumerates the *individual characters* of that string:

If you run the following in Script Editor:

```applescript
set dFolder to "/foo/bar"
tell application "Preview"
  every item of dFolder
end tell
```

you'll see the following in the Result pane (the enclosing `tell application "Preview"` block is incidental):

```applescript
{"/", "f", "o", "o", "/", "b", "a", "r"}
```

Answer (score 0):

me newbee - my solution: (bad hack but works)
Input is a list of files. Store output in variable and use later.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    #input consists of several files
    #extract from list first file w path
    set myfile to first item of input as string
    #reverse file w path 
    set elifeym to reverse of characters of myfile as text
    #find first :  
    set theTrimLength to offset of ":" in elifeym
    #trim from : until the end of the string
    set theText to characters (theTrimLength) thru -1 of elifeym as string
    #reverse again
    set mypath to reverse of characters of theText as text
    #create link to mypath as alias (if you don't, Automator crashed, when using the folder text 
    set myfolder to alias mypath
    # nothing of this worked for me.... reason unknown
    #set mypath to (get folder of myfile) as string
    #set mypwd to POSIX path of myfile
    
    return myfolder
end run
```